# jQuery show() and hide() for multiple links on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am coding a webpage that will have three forms for corresponding questions hidden in divs-  I'm using a simple .accordion-toggle for this functionality in bootstrap's framework.

- When a user chooses the 'Ask a question' button it toggles down (using .accordion-toggle) and a form appears- using hide() the 'Ask a question' link should disappear.
- The form will have a Submit button to post the form, but also a **cancel link**- the cancel link should trigger the form to collapse(using bootstrap .collapse), simultaneously the 'Ask a question' button should reappear.

  I'm able to get it working using the show() and hide() method in jQuery. However with three cancel buttons on the same page I'm not sure how to attach a unique identifier to each link to properly collapse the correct div.

The fiddle below is the closest solution thus far.

```
See @DanielAlmeida Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/ek57ao0y/
    <div class='form form0'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class='showForm' data-target='.form1'>Show form   1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class='showForm' data-target='.form2'>Show form 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class='showForm' data-target='.form3'>Show form 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class='showForm' data-target='.form4'>Show form 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class='form form1'>
    
      <h3>Form 1</h3>
      <div>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>
    
      <p>
        <a href="#" class='cancel' data-target='.form0'>Cancel</a>
      </p>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class='form form2'>
    
      <h3>Form 2</h3>
      <div>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>
    
      <p>
        <a href="#" class='cancel' data-target='.form0'>Cancel</a>
      </p>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class='form form3'>
    
      <h3>Form 3</h3>
      <div>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>
    
      <p>
        <a href="#" class='cancel' data-target='.form0'>Cancel</a>
      </p>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class='form form4'>
    
      <h3>Form 4</h3>
      <div>
        <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      </div>
    
      <p>
        <a href="#" class='cancel' data-target='.form0'>Cancel</a>
      </p>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you could use targets in your links.. see this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ek57ao0y/)

Comment: @DanielAlmeida  - Thanks, How do you target the specific form to hide? With your current code all form links disappear when you click 'show form' link.

Comment: Remove the `form` class from the first div.. change this `class='form form0'` to `class='form0'` [check this example](https://jsfiddle.net/6dy6q75n/3)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing a bit of your code around.. by making sure you are hiding and showing the correct element. The below should do the job for you.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".submit-collapse").click(function(){
      $(".contact-form").show();
      $(".submit-collapse").hide();
  });
  $(".cancel-link").click(function(){
      $(".contact-form").hide();
      $(".submit-collapse").show();
  })
});
```

```css
.contact-form{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-trigger top-spaced hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="panel panel-default no-border">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="drk-grey">
        Have another question? <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed collapsed grn-btn full-window-btn submit-collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#question-about-app-process">Submit Your Question </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <form class="contact-form" action="/mailers/faq_contact_us" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="L+9iNJ7+yKMBBIFsSv0nEzet6tit4bfxTaoUNbopARhIzoN/GL3fn40AaY1sV095jddz6fXzs0p20axPIfki+A==" />
          <div class="spaced">
            <label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required="required" />
          </div>
          <div class="row spaced">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="email">Email</label><input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required="required" email="true" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="primary_phone">Phone</label><input type="tel" name="primary_phone" id="primary_phone" class="form-control" required="required" phone="true" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="spaced">
            <label for="message">Message</label><textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" required="required" rows="10" maxLength="1000">
</textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="spaced">
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit Question" class="btn btn-small text-center" /><a class="accordion-toggle collapsed collapsed cancel-link" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#question-about-app-process">Cancel</a>
          </div></form>

  </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I will have three other forms on the page with the same functionality. So I'm not sure how to specify the correct hide() and show() for the corresponding forms.

Comment: you have 3 other forms? what the same forms? can you update your answer so i can see what you mean.

Comment: Basically if you were to replicate what you did two more times that would be what I'm trying to accomplish. So we would have: 
 - Have another question? Submit Your Answer.
-  Have another question2? Submit Your Answer.
-  Have another question3? Submit Your Answer.
This is key b/c when I tried this earlier hitting the cancel link for form two would toggle form one, instead of the corresponding form.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

"I'm not sure how to attach a unique identifier to each link to properly collapse the correct div"

You can use the parent() function. Example: this code removes everything inside the parent div...where this link is:

```
<div>blablabla something <a href='#null' onclick="$(this).parent(\'div\').remove();">Remove</a></div>
```

In your cause, you will not use "remove", call the colapse function instead.